# How to execute multiple methods in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

```
def parse(self,response):
  print("parse!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  yield  scrapy.Request("http://xx.com", callback=self.parseHeader,meta={'item': item})
  yield  scrapy.Request("http://xx.com ", callback=self.parseBody,meta={'item': item})
  yield  scrapy.Request("http://xx.com ", callback=self.parseFooter,meta={'item': item})


def parseHeader(self,response):
  print("parseHeader!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  item = ItemHeader()
  #...
  yield item

def parseBody(self,response):
  print("parseBody!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  item = ItemBody()
  #...
  yield item

def parseFooter(self,response):
  print("parseFooter!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
  item = ItemFooter()
  #...
  yield item
```

Executing the above code results in the following result.
Current results

```
parse!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
↓
parseHeader!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
↓
pipeline
↓
Closing spider (finished)
```

The only method of "parseHeader" will be executed
Under it is not executed
Changing yield to return does not change the result.

I would like to change the above result as follows.

```
parse!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
↓
parseHeader!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
↓
pipeline
↓
parseBody!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
↓
pipeline
↓
parseFooter!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
↓
pipeline
↓
Closing spider (finished)
```

How could I do that?
Please let me know if you know something that becomes a hint?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single response and want to parse multiple things out of it, you can separate parsing logic into different methods and just call them as normal python methods that return an item:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request("http://xx.com", 
                         callback=self.parse_item, 
                         meta={'item': item})

def parse_item(self, response):
    # either return everything as one item:
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['header'] = self.parse_header(response)
    item['body'] = self.parse_body(response)
    item['footer'] = self.parse_footer(response)
    yield item
    # or as multiple items:
    yield self.parse_header(response)
    yield self.parse_body(response)
    yield self.parse_footer(response)

def parse_header(self, response):
    print("parseHeader!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    item = ItemHeader()
    return item

def parse_body(self, response):
    print("parseBody!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    item = ItemBody()
    return item

def parse_footer(self, response):
    print("parseFooter!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    item = ItemFooter()
    return item
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Although there was not enough explanation, there is a for statement in parse_body
As you taught, the execution of pipeline was only the beginning of the for a statement.

Comment: For statement? Can you post that? I suggest reviewing [architectual overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) of scrapy if you're trying to understand when and where pipelines are being executed.